# htmltidy linter does not have a file in directory usr/local/bin

Tags: html, npm, sublimetext, htmltidy, sublimelinter

So I recently installed a few linters for sublimelinter and so far all work except htmltidy. I installed as directed using terminal (I'm running OSX) in the following way:

```
sudo npm install -g htmltidy
```

This worked for CSSLint, JSHint etc. but not htmltidy. i checked usr/local/bin and it turns out that there is no .js file for htmltidy. How could I fix this?

Comment: On my system the binary is called `tidy`.

Comment: I searched for the binary with that name but to no avail

Answer (score 1):

Run `whereis htmltidy`. If that does not return anything close out of terminal and open it back up. The installer might of added something to your path but didn't resource it.

If that doesn't work run `sudo find -name htmltidy /`

Comment: I ran the second command you suggested and this came up in terminal: find: illegal option -- R
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm on my phone, it should be lowercase. Just updated the answer

Comment: A good comment was made above that the binary is called tidy. Search for that as well.

Comment: I used the lowercase command but it results in the same error: -- r usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression] find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]

Comment: Sorry remove the -r option.

Comment: it looks like it is in the wrong location. Thanks for the help so far by the way but I'm afraid I'm not sure what step to take now. The message in terminal says:          find: htmltidy: No such file or directory